# Laravel Generate Resource fails in Sublime Text when asking me to confirm if I want a model created

Tags: laravel, sublimetext2, sublimetext, way-generators

I get an error only when doing the generate resource command in sublime text 2.  All other commands seem to work.  The issue seems to be around the fact it asks me if I want it to create a model (which I do), but it doesn't allow me to do the input.  If I do it inside of cmd prompt it works.  I get a runtime exception of aborted as the error.

Comment: Have you tried the [`Laravel 4 Artisan`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Laravel%204%20Artisan) plugin as a replacement? It also includes a generate resource command.

Comment: MattDMo - I believe that is what I am using.  I got the link from an article by Jeffrey Way.  Looks like this is the same (but maybe I am wrong).

Comment: Well, there is also [`Laravel Generator`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Laravel%20Generator), which is ST2-only. Open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User` and [edit] your question with the plugin you're using. Also, please add the full text of the exception you're getting. Finally, please open the console via `View -> Show Console` and paste in any relevant error messages that are there. Thanks.